# How to pass parameters to a controller action method from a jquery callback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a web app using asp.net mvc4. I have an ajax call to a controller action method, and on success callback I need to redirect to a different action method which has 2 parameters. I know window.location.href works for redirecting, but I am not sure how to pass the parameters. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the query string .. it will work fine.

Comment: Help us help you by showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is what I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, to call a specific controller with action and parameter.

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" +"/"+ parameter ;
```

Separate your each parameter with a "/".

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters as follows:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { param1 = "", param2 = "" })';
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName" />
<input type="button" onclick="MyFunction()"value="Send" />

<div id="UpdateDiv"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function MyFunction() {
var data = {
UserName: $('#UserName').val(),
};
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/GetEmployer",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify(data),
uccess: function (mydata) {
$("#UpdateDiv").html(mydata);
history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + href, href); // This Code lets you to change url  howyouwant (Optional)
});
return false;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployer(string UserName,MyModel model)
{
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("YOURPARTİALVİEW", model);
return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Required for Json

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
ViewData.Model = model;
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,viewName);
var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
}
```